# Connect Weblogic server to Eclipse Error: "does not contain a valid WebLogic Server install or the installed version is not supported"

Tags: java, eclipse, weblogic, weblogic12c, eclipse-photon

I'm trying to connect a weblogic server to my eclipse (photon) and I keep getting this error message:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqF7c.png)
"does not contain a valid WebLogic Server install or the installed version is not supported"

I've tried installing 3 different types of eclipse (Photon, Eclipse IDE for Java Developers - 2021-09 and Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers - 2021-09) but I have the same error on all of them.

I know that I have configured the weblogic server correctly because I can access it as shown:
[Weblogic Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rkaei.png)

Shouldn't it be looking for the startWebLogic file or something? Because that's where I'm pointing it at.

I have tried doing what other threads do but they don't work for me.

Basically I have 2 questions:

- How do I fix this error?
- What file does this pop-up is looking for?

Comment: Did you install Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers ?

Answer (score 0):

The WebLogc Home Folder must set to point to your WebLogic installation and not to a domain folder (as you did). Locate the wlserver folder under your WebLogic installation and set it up in Eclipse.

Comment: I've already done that too, doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You have to look to the "wlserver" folder, I just got it fixed, also with Oracle 12c.
The Server I linked was: C:\WL\wls12213\wlserver

And then you can continue, also the configuration guide will ask you for the domain, that you have to had already configured.
In my case: C:\WL\weblogic_server_12.2.1

I'm using Spring Tools Studio 4.6.1